# Regex for email address not accepting .cat

Tags: regex

I have never really studied regex so do not really ungerstand it

I have the following regex expression that tests email addresses

```
^([\\w]+)(\\.[\\w]+)*@([\\w\\-]+\\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,4}$
```

when i enter `example@example.cat` it fails but when i enter `example@example.com` it works... can anyone explain why this is?

**EDIT**

Have been looking into the code and would this regex fail for the above email addresses?

```
^\\w[-._\\w]*\\w@\\w[-._\\w]*\\w\\.\\w{2,6}$
```

Comment: That should be fine for both of them; can you construct a test-case?

Comment: This doesn't work for either example.  Replace every instance of double-backslash (`\\\`) with a single backslash (`\\`) and it should work for both examples.

Comment: I think David's comment might explain why you are having trouble, though I should point out that in some contexts (Python r"" quoting) you need a single backslash and in some contexts (Python "" quoting) you need to double them. I don't even know what language you're using; these are important details for knowing if a regexp will work properly or not.

Comment: This isn't a good regexp to use to match email addresses, anyway; it rejects many valid email addresses. I get really frustrated when people refuse `slamb+foo@slamb.org`; the extra `+foo` helps me filter the mail appropriately. For the most part, you shouldn't try to validate the part before the `@`. And there have been [proposed top-level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_top-level_domain) domains with more than four characters, so it's bad that you are rejecting `foo@bar.berlin`. I'd recommend something much looser.

Comment: i am using Java, HTML and tapestry for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That regexp will not fail for `.cat` but match `.com` you must have something other issues causing the behavior you are seeing, here is an explanation of the `regex`:

```
^([\w]+)(\.[\w]+)*@([\w-]+\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,4}$/

^ Start of string

1st Capturing group ([\w]+) 
Char class [\w] infinite to 1 times matches one of the following chars: \w
\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 

2nd Capturing group (\.[\w]+) infinite to 0 times 
\. Literal .
Char class [\w] infinite to 1 times matches one of the following chars: \w
\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 
@ Literal @

3rd Capturing group ([\w-]+\.) 5 to 1 times 
Char class [\w-] infinite to 1 times matches one of the following chars: \w-
\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 
\. Literal .

4th Capturing group ([A-Za-z]) 4 to 2 times 
Char class [A-Za-z] matches one of the following chars: A-Za-z

$ End of string
```

And the second will also accept both given the right escaping (in most languages the double backslashes would cause both not to match):

```
/^\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.\w{2,6}$/

^ Start of string

\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 
Char class [-._\w] infinite to 0 times matches one of the following chars: -._\w
\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 
\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 

@ Literal @

\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 
Char class [-._\w] infinite to 0 times matches one of the following chars: -._\w

\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 
\w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 

\. Literal .

\w 6 to 2 times Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 

$ End of string
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation... can you look at the edit ive made and see would this cause the fail to the email?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I suspect the double backslashes are giving you problems (which I removed) but both can only ever accept both or reject both. What environment/language are you using?